# How do I replace special class with another in jquery?

Tags: jquery, class, replace

E.g:

```
<li class="dataItem ready igto" status="ready">I will change status to waiting</li>
```

and then ,I just want to change the **ready class** to **waiting**.THe normal way is to **removing** the **class ready** and adding new class!

**and another situation is how to replace multi class at once!? E.g:**

```
<!-- replace done wainting error to ready -->
<li class="dataItem done igto" status="ready">I will change status to ready</li>
<li class="dataItem waiting igto" status="ready">I will change status to ready</li>
<li class="dataItem error igto" status="ready">I will change status to ready</li>
```

to :

```
<li class="dataItem ready igto" status="ready">I will change status to waiting</li>
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The best way is to do as you say, remove the class then add it again, as there's no "switching" classes in jQuery.

```
$('.dataItem').removeClass('ready').addClass('waiting');
```

You can replace multiple classes by passing in more than one class into `.removeClass()`:

```
$('.dataItem').removeClass('done waiting error').addClass('ready');
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use [`$.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to achieve this.

```
$("p").click(function(){
  // Replace 'done' with 'waiting' or 'waiting' with 'done'
  $(this).toggleClass("done waiting");   
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wH9x3/

Comment: Not reliable, for it will toggle everytime, even when we don't want it to.

Comment: @sidney The point is to show how `$.fn.toggleClass` works. It's up to those using it to conditionally wrap it to execute only under certain circumstances.